# Count values by groups

Tags: aggregate, graphite, grafana

I currently send events to graphite like
`server.my_value` with a count that varies between 1 and 1000

I'd like to plot a graph that will show me how many of these `my_value` I received by groups of 100 (so 1,4,7 and 89 will be counted toward the 1-100 group and etc)

so to illustrate, lets say I sent these values in a specific time

```
1
3
45
13
299
455
74
924
```

the groups will be

```
1-100: 5
200-300: 1
300-400: 0
400-500: 1
500-600: 0
600-700: 0 
700-800: 0
800-900: 0
900-1000: 1
```

so I would have 10 lines, each represent a group

This could be in a histogram, but it won't show me the changes with time

Is it possible to aggregate values by ranges?

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid using downsampled data by only querying for small time intervals and do not cross the aggregation boundary defined in your Graphite storage schema then you can just use the [new histogram feature](http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/heatmap/#histograms-and-buckets) in the [Graph panel](http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/graph/#x-axis-mode) in Grafana or the new [Heatmap panel](http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/heatmap/#heatmap-panel) to get a histogram over time. (For example, if you have the storage schema `15s:7d,1m:21d,15m:5y` and you stay within the 7 day boundary.) Here is an [example from the Grafana demo site](http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/new-features-in-v4-3?panelId=4&fullscreen&edit&orgId=1).

I don't think there is a good way to aggregate values by ranges in a Graphite query if you want to aggregate for larger time intervals. However, it seems to be possible to do it by aggregating the data in statsd:

http://dieter.plaetinck.be/post/histogram-statsd-graphing-over-time-with-graphite/